# Use glob to get all files with names that match a particular text

Tags: python, glob

I am using glob library to get all the image files from a particular path like this:

```
glob(join(tmp_dir,"*.{}".format('jpg')))
```

How can I modify it to get only the files that end up with the string "-1.jpg"?

Comment: and `glob(os.path.join(tmp_dir,"*-1.jpg"))` doesn't work?

Comment: @Abdou Of course! I feel silly. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just the `os` module:

```
import os
[os.path.join(tmp_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(tmp_dir) if x.endswith('-1.jpg')]
```